# Trouble plotting a solution curve with dsolve

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do my assignments which is plotting a direction fields and a solution curve that passes a given point and having a trouble doing this particular differential equation: `y'=1-x*y, y(0)=0.`

My code is :

```
syms x y;
y1=dsolve('Dy=1-x*y','y(0)=0','x');
y1=expand(y1);
ezplot(y1,[-10 10 -10 10]);
```

And it got some error about the input i believe, it says:

> Error using inlineeval and error in expression, input must be real and
>   full and so on...

I have had success with other differential equations but this one is still miserable.

Comment: What is this `x` alone at the end of the `dsolve` function ? Is that a condition ? Matlab recommand to use symbolic variable and not vector of character. So if you want to indicate that we use `dy/dx` you should write `diff(y,x) == 1-x*y(x)` instead.

Comment: Also Matlab won't be able to solve all the differential equation. In this case you should compute the solution by hand. With your example `y = sqrt(pi/2)*exp(-x^2/2)*erfi(x/sqrt(2))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this is a comment, but since I still don't have enough reputation to do so I'm answering here :P

Apparently the solution `y1` for your equation is something like

`y1 = -(2^(1/2)*pi^(1/2)*exp(-x^2/2)*erf((2^(1/2)*x*1i)/2)*1i)/2`

The `erf` function needs a real input, but in this case you have a `1i` complex term which is causing the problem.